# Show messagebox if datetime is reached?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, dispatchertimer

I need help with DateTime.
I want my application to check if DateTime end is up and gives me a messagebox.
How do I write that?
Code:

```
private void listjob()
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(listjob3_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
private void listjob3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listbox3job())
    {
        DateTime? start = DateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime? end = DateTimePicker2.Value;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if (?) // here is what I want it to check if end time is started
        {
           Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("End Time started");
           DispatcherTimer timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
           timer.Stop();
           timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Application is WPF modified with compatible DateTimePicker.

Comment: I know you're just starting out in software, but you need to start using better variable and method names right now.  `listbox3job` is no good, even for a prototype.  `listjob3` as a control name is no good either.  Sorry to be picky, but pick up the habit now before it's too late

Comment: @KierenJohnstone
Any suggestions for better names? :)

Comment: Whatever they represent - is it a list of pending calculation jobs? Active print jobs?  Job titles to be added to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm grossly misunderstanding what you want:

```
if (now >= end)
```

or in other words, if the current time is greater than or equal to the end time. If you just wanted to know if the current time is **past the end time** then:

```
if (now > end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(end<= now)
```

It's just like that. If you have some issue with the type, use ToShortDateString() or other properties

Comment: I don't think the `ToShortDateString()` is necessary. `DateTime`s don't have a format, only their string representations do.